# Is it possible to take input from Android Presentation or Secondary Display?

Tags: android, flutter

I am working on a POS system application in Flutter. The app will be used on POS terminals that have two displays one small display will be facing customers.
To detect and connect with the secondary display I am using [Flutter Presentation Display Package](https://pub.dev/packages/presentation_displays).

For development, I am using a simulation of a secondary display from the Android developer option.

**Problem:**
**Not able to click buttons on simulator secondary display.**

**Here is my secondary display code:**
nothing happens on Inkwell(" !!! Button Click !!! ");

```dart
class SecondaryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondaryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondaryScreenState createState() => _SecondaryScreenState();
}

class _SecondaryScreenState extends State<SecondaryScreen> {
  String value = "init";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SecondaryDisplay(
      callback: (argument) {
        setState(() {
          value = '$value $argument';
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(value),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    value = '!!!BUTTON CLICK!!';
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: const Text('Hello!!!!!'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[Simulator Display Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zAfF.png)